# preg_match multiple things in one regex

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex that matches multiple things.

What im trying to do, is send a mail if the url doesnt contain certain words.
(.xml, .jpg, .ico)

My try, that didnt work:

```
if (!preg_match("/(\.xml)|(\.jpg)|(\.ico)/", $url))
mail("mail@mail.com", "the url doesnt contain .xml, .jpg or .ico", $url);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there.  Enclose the three extension types in one `()` group separated by `|` and keep the `.` outside of it.  Also, I've added a `$` to the end to indicate that the file extension occurs as the last thing in the string so something like `example.xml.com` doesn't accidentally match.

```
if (!preg_match("/\.(xml|jpg|ico)$/", $url)) {

}
```

Comment: @Kristian Don't. Regex is a very complicated topic where experience & practice play a big role.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth: As Michael said, don't. Even after few months I'm sometimes confused

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php 
$url = "imaeg.ic";
if (!preg_match("/(\.xml|\.jpg|\.ico)/", $url))
   die("mail sent 2");
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/c340b/1